# Replace icon element after click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script in jQuery:

```
$('.data-table').on('click', 'td', function () {
      var row = table.row(this).data();
      let mainProduct = {{ $id }};
      $.get("{{ route('related.product.add')}}" + '/' + mainProduct + '/' + row.id, function (data, status) {});
      $.get("{{ route('related.product.destroyAjax') }}" + '/' + mainProduct + '/' + row.id, function (data, status) {});
});
```

This code adds and removes items from my database (script post to PHP / Laravel).

I have a span to remove an item:

```
<i id="1" class="fas fa-minus removeItem"></I>
```

And to add an item:

```
<i id="1" class="fas fa-plus addItem"></I>
```

ID numbers vary depending on the product.

I would like to click on "removeItem" (minus icon) to add "addItem" (plus icon).

After clicking on "addItem" (plus icon) there would appear an element for "removeItem" (minus icon).

So if I clicked add element - then we replace the icon n and delete the element and vice versa. So if I click the icon to delete the item - it should appear for adding.

In my code I have two methods to add and delete. I know they can't be at the same time. I just don't know how to assign them to individual buttons.

Comment: Can you show your html code as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your onclick event like below:

```js
$('.data-table').on('click', 'td i', function() {
  var rowId = $(this).attr('id');
  let mainProduct = {{ $id }};
  let record = this;
  if ($(record).hasClass('addItem')) {
    $.get("{{ route('related.product.add') }}" + '/' + mainProduct + '/' + rowId, function(data, status) {});
    $(record).addClass('removeItem fa-minus');
    $(record).removeClass('addItem fa-plus');
  } else {
    $.get("{{ route('related.product.destroyAjax') }}" + '/' + mainProduct + '/' + rowId, function(data, status) {});
    $(record).addClass('addItem fa-plus');
    $(record).removeClass('removeItem fa-minus');
  }
  console.log(record);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You need to assign `this` to a variable on the click function

```
var element = this;
```

After a service response, call the below function and pass `element` as the argument:

```
function switchState(element) {
  if($(element).hasClass('addItem')) {
    $(element).addClass('removeItem fa-minus');
    $(element).removeClass('addItem fa-plus');
  } else {
    $(element).addClass('addItem fa-plus');
    $(element).removeClass('removeItem fa-minus');
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you. In this element I have this: https://ibb.co/z4d95BW ([object HTMLTableCellElement]).  and yours code not working :(

Comment: Change your onlick event to `i` tag instead of `td`. It will work

Comment: I have this code now: https://pastebin.com/dkb9RrQB . When I click in my icon https://ibb.co/Xp4QVCZ (icon Is inside datatable) I have this result in console: https://ibb.co/TThCrGF -  icon is not change :(

Comment: It's not help :( https://ibb.co/TWbZc2T my actual code: https://pastebin.com/kABTwumt

Comment: Yes @operloa, I have edited the onclick event in the answer. please check that.

Comment: Thank you. Now I have error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'row.id')

Comment: in this line: $.get("http://roelle.test/_admin/related-products/add" + '/' + mainProduct + '/' + row.id, function(data, status) {});

Comment: `var rowId = $(this).attr('id');` include this line instead of `var row = table.row(this).data();` and use `rowId` instead of `row.id`

Answer (score 0):

Since you claimed to be a new web developer, I'd happy to post an alternative approach. It's based on the checkbox state + showing a correct icon.

Working example: https://codepen.io/zvona/pen/qBbrLag?editors=1111

The HTML looks like this (no *[fontawesome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_Awesome)* in this case, but you can replace those with the correct icons):

```
<form>
  <input type='checkbox' id='makeQuery' />
  <i class='addItem'>+</i>
  <i class='removeItem'>-</i>
  <span>Some Item Name</span>
</form>
```

The idea is to use CSS for displaying the correct icon based whether a checkbox is checked or not (see the CodePen for detailed CSS).

Now, based on the state of the checkbox, we make a query with JavaScript to a correct endpoint:

```
const makeQuery = document.querySelector('#makeQuery');

makeQuery.addEventListener('change', () => {
  const query = (makeQuery.checked) ? '/addItem' : '/removeItem';

  << here you make the query >>
});
```

I hope this doesn't confuse you, but to give idea(s) on how you can approach your problem.